# How to search, replace specific hex code in automated way

Tags: linux, bash

I have a 100M row file that has some encoding problems -- was "originally" EBCDIC, saved as US-ASCII, now UTF-8.  I don't know much more about its heritage, sorry -- I've just been asked to analyze the content.

The "cents" character from EBCDIC is "hidden" in this file in random places, causing all sorts of errors.  Here is more on this bugger: [cents character in hex](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a2/index.htm)

Converting this file using iconv -f foo -t UTF-8 -c  is not working -- the cents character prevails.

When I use hex editor, I can find the appearance of 0xC2 0xA2 (c2a2).  But in a BIG file, this isn't ideal.   Sed doesn't work at hex level, so...  Not sure about tr -- I only really use it for carriage return / new line.

What linux utility / command can I use to find and delete this character reasonably quickly on very big files?

2 parts:

```
 1 -- utility / command to find / count the number of these occurrences (octal \242)
 2 -- command to replace (this works  tr '\242' ' ' < source > output )
```

How the text appears on my ubuntu terminal:

```
1019EQ?IT DEPT GENERATED
```

With xxd, how it looks at hex level (ascii to the side looks the same as above):

```
0000000: 3130 3139 4551 a249 5420 4445 5054 2047 454e 4552 4154 4544 0d0a
```

With xxd, how it looks with "show ebcdic" -- here, just showing the ebcdic from side:

```
......s.....&....+........
```

So hex "a2" is the culprit.  I'm now trying xxd -E foo | grep a2 to count the instances up.

Adding output from od -ctxl, rather than xxd, for those interested:

```
 0000000   1   0   1   9   E   Q 242   I   T       D   E   P   T       G
          31  30  31  39  45  51  a2  49  54  20  44  45  50  54  20  47
 0000020   E   N   E   R   A   T   E   D  \r  \n
          45  4e  45  52  41  54  45  44  0d  0a
```

Comment: Note that I also tried encoding using iconv from EBCDIC to UTF-8 -- didn't kill this hex code!!

Comment: Why not `sed 's/¢//g'`? `sed` doesn't need to support it, the shell does. And if the shell doesn't, then why not `sed 's/\xc2\xa2//g'`?

Comment: rid, totally old-school -- my first commercial programming gig involved writing an EBCDIC to ASCII conversion program in COBOL that was callable via JCL and avoided the $250,000 / year we paid IBM for a similar utility.  That was in 1990.  Finding EBCDIC again in 2013 was a shock!

Comment: I was an inexpensive intern whom they paid very little to write said program -- the ROI was gianormous to my employer.

Comment: rid -- this command did not work:  sed 's/\xc2\xa2//g' source > new.  The cents sign stayed in the file

Comment: Hrm, that's strange. Maybe try with `xxd`? I'm not entirely sure how to use it, it's been a while, but check out the man page. The idea would be to transform the binary to the text representation of the hex pairs, then use `sed` to remove the offending pairs, then use `xxd` to transform it again to binary. Apparently, it even supports EBCDIC, if that's of any use.

Comment: @rid, @ToddCurry: sed doesn't do `\x` conversions. bash does, but not inside `''`; you need to use the `$''` form. Try this: `sed $'s/\xc2\xa2//g'. (or you might prefer to translate them to something else.)

Comment: I sometimes use sed with hex codes, so my approach would be: < file.txt sed -e 's/\xA2/¢/g' > file_converted.txt

Comment: NB: this method should be fast enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say the file was *converted* what do you mean? Do you mean the binary file was simply dumped from an IBM 360 to another ASCII based computer, or was the file itself converted over to ASCII when it was transferred over?

The question is whether the file is actually in a well encoded state or not. The other question is how do you want the file encoded?

On my Mac (which uses UTF-8 by default, just like Linux systems), I have no problem using `sed` to get rid of the `¢` character:

Here's my file:

```
$ cat test.txt
This is a test --¢-- TEST TEST
$ od -ctx1 test.txt
0000000    T   h   i   s       i   s       a       t   e   s   t       -
           54  68  69  73  20  69  73  20  61  20  74  65  73  74  20  2d
0000020    -   ¢  **   -   -       T   E   S   T       T   E   S   T  \n
           2d  c2  a2  2d  2d  20  54  45  53  54  20  54  45  53  54  0a
0000040
```

You can see that `cat` has no problems printing out that `¢` character. And, you can see in the `od` dump the `c2a2` encoding of the `¢` character.

```
$ sed 's/¢/$/g' test.txt > new_test.txt
$ cat new_test.txt
This is a test --$-- TEST TEST
$ od -ctx1  new_test.txt
0000000    T   h   i   s       i   s       a       t   e   s   t       -
           54  68  69  73  20  69  73  20  61  20  74  65  73  74  20  2d
0000020    -   $   -   -       T   E   S   T       T   E   S   T  \n    
           2d  24  2d  2d  20  54  45  53  54  20  54  45  53  54  0a    
0000037
```

Here's my sed has no problems changing that `¢` into a `$` sign. The dump now shows that this test file is equivalent to a strictly ASCII encoded file. That two hexadecimal digit encoded `¢` is now a nice clean single hexadecimal digit encoded `$`.

It looks like `sed` can handle your issue.

If you want to use this file on a Windows system, you can convert the file to the standard Windows Code Page 1252:

```
$ iconv -f utf8 -t cp1252 test.txt > new_test.txt 
$ cat new_test.txt 
This is a test --?-- TEST TEST
$ od -ctx1  new_test.txt
0000000    T   h   i   s       i   s       a       t   e   s   t       -
           54  68  69  73  20  69  73  20  61  20  74  65  73  74  20  2d
0000020    - 242   -   -       T   E   S   T       T   E   S   T  \n    
           2d  a2  2d  2d  20  54  45  53  54  20  54  45  53  54  0a    
0000037
```

Here's the file now in Codepage 1252 just like the way Windows likes it! Note that the `¢` is now a nice hex 242 character.

So, what is exactly the issue? Do you need to file in *pure ASCII defined* 127 characters? Do you need the file encoded, so Windows machines can work on it? Are you having problems entering the ¢ character?

Let me know. I'm not from the government, and yet I'm here to help you.

Comment: Agree with all above, especially 'is file in in a well encoded state?' . @ToddCurry if this is important, I would step back, get perl running and use the EBCIDIC conversion packages available. (Or export correctly from your original source). Good luck!

Comment: Good questions and points -- based on this, and some experimentation with xxd from another tipster, I've added to the question above.

Comment: You are seeing the c2 representation of the ¢ symbol, not the a2 representation.  The "hidden" representation, a2, is vexing.

Comment: @ToddCurry No, you are seeing in the `od -ctx1` dump both `c2` and `a2`. In UTF-8, the cent symbol is two characters. The ¢ symbol is over the `c2`, the `**` is over the `a2` is just a place holder.

Comment: @ToddCurry - I see your confusion. It's not the `c2` which is the problem. The cent symbol is represented with **TWO** eight bit bytes while most of the other common characters (the same 95 printable characters that were defined in ASCII) are represented with a single eight bit byte in UTF-8. As you saw with my `sed` example, when I changed `¢` to `$`, the length of the file was reduced by a single eight bit byte. The original file took up 32 eight bit bytes while the one with the `$` takes up only 31 eight bit bytes. Use `sed` to change `¢` to a space, and that will solve your issue.

Comment: @ToddCurry I just looked at `xxd`. You're better off with `od` which allows you to do all sorts of neat stuff. `xxd` doesn't do UTF-8 very well. The cent character is represented as `..` in my dump. Again, I think `sed` will do it for you. If nothing else, make sure `shopt -s xpg_echo` is set, and then use `sed 's/$(echo "\0xc2\0xa2")/ /g'` which will change `¢` to a blank.

Comment: David, thanks for your tenacity here; added od -ctxl output for you above.  As you can see, somehow in translation the a2 portion persisted.  I'm going to add your sed command to the answer so I can close this out.  thanks very much.  TC

Comment: @ToddCurry Ah! I now see! Your file is encoded as a Code Page 1252 Windows file. Take a look at my last `od` output. You can see the same `242` as a cent character. All you have to do is reverse what I did: Do a `iconv -f cp1252 -t utf8` and that will give you a valid UTF-8 encoded file. Then `sed` can get rid of that `¢` symbol via `sed 's/¢/ /g'`. Or skip `iconv` and set `shopt -s xp_echo` to set the extended echo (You're using BASH, right?), then do `sed `s$(echo "\0xa2")/ /g`. to get rid of it.